# How do I query a row of cells containing text and return a true or false response

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a row of text containing either the words RED or GREEN and I want to change the colour of a new cell to red if any of the previous cells have the word RED in them or to the colour green if ALL cells have the word GREEN in it.

I have tried building IF and OR strings to identify this querry with no luck, any advice?

I have B2 - F2 with either the words RED or GREEN in them. I want to conditionally format G2 so turn Red if any of the cells between B2 and F2 have the word RED in them

Comment: Is number of cells in a Row fixed? Say A1 thru A10 and you want to apply the condition for any cell updated after A11 onward?

Comment: I have B2 - F2 with either the words RED or GREEN in them. I want to conditionally format G2 so turn Red if any of the cells between B2 and F2 have the word RED in them. Does that help clear it up?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using Conditional Formatting.

Click Cell G2 and go to Conditional Formatting. New Rule --> Use a Formula to determine which cells to format.

Put the following Rule and select your choice of background color.

```
=COUNTIF(B2:F2,"GREEN")=COLUMN($F$2)-COLUMN($A$2)
```

Then create next rule for the same cell as

```
=COUNTIF(B2:F2,"RED")>0
```

and select your choice of background color.

Use format painter and apply the formatting to all applicable cells in the column or drag cell G2 below up to intended rows.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]